# tables with multiple varbinary columns

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

If i have a table with varbinary(Max) datatype and have FILESTREAM attributes on the column. Now I need to have to store another binary data but without FILESTREAM attribute. So, if I add another column with VARBINARY(MAX) datatypes on the same table would there be any performance issue? Do I gain faster performance if I separate a table with FILESTREAM attributes and Create another separate table to store other VARBINARY(MAX) data?

Answer (score 0):

for your this question.you can.
Filestream is the new feature in sqlserver2008,and in 2012 ,that change the name ,call fileTable.
I tested it.this feature is use the DB manage the file .and up file about 5M/s.
for your other column,if you not open the filestream,the file will be change the binary ,and store in sqlserver data file.
open the filestream,the file will store the server, and managed by sqlserver.
for your second question,i am not 100% sure,but if you use the filestream,it's will gain more effiencit,need to attention the backup and store.

one years ago,i implemented this function in our system,and i have the shcame,if you want ,i will send you.
sorry,my english is not good.

Answer (score 0):

your performance might be effected if you add another VARBINARY(MAX) on the same table

When the FILESTREAM attribute is set, SQL Server stores the BLOB data in the NT file system and keeps a pointer the file, in the table. this allows SQL Server to take advantage of the NTFS I/O streaming capabilities. and reduces overhead on the SQL engine

The MAX types (varchar, nvarchar and varbinary) and in your case VARBINARY(MAX) datatype cannot be stored internally as a contiguous memory area, since they can possibly grow up to 2Gb. So they have to be represented by a streaming interface.

and they will effect performance very much

if you are sure your files are small you can go for VARBINARY(MAX) other wise if they are larger thab 2gb FILESTREAM is the best option for you

and yeah i would suggest you Create another separate table to store other VARBINARY(MAX) data